# customize messcall sequence diagram position

Tags: pgf-umlsd

In a sequence diagram, I need to move the `messcall` arrow a little down, is that possible ?

[image]

```
\usepackage{pgf-umlsd}
. . .
\begin{figure*}[h]
\centering
\begin{sequencediagram}
    \newthread{S}{Dealer}
    \newinst[4]{U}{$u_i$}
     . . . 
    \begin{messcall}{S}
       {public $R(x,y)$, send $\mathcal{I}^i$}{U}
    \end{messcall}
     . . . 
 \end{sequencediagram}
 \end{figure*}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `\postlevel` macro mentioned in the manual can be used for that, it seems:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgf-umlsd}
\begin{document}
\begin{sequencediagram}
    \newthread{S}{Dealer}
    \newinst[4]{U}{$u_i$}
    \begin{call}{S}
       {foo}{U}
      {bar}
    \end{call}
    \postlevel % <----- add this
    \begin{messcall}{S}
       {public $R(x,y)$, send $\mathcal{I}^i$}{U}
    \end{messcall}
 \end{sequencediagram}
\end{document}
```

Comment: thank you @Torbjørn T, I tried it but in a wrong place so it doesn't worked (inside the first call at the end)